# How to format PHPDoc comment for complex return values

Tags: php, comments, phpdoc

I have a function which returns something like the following structure:

```
array('form' => $form, 'options' => $options)
```

How to correctly format this return value in function comment?

My guess is:

```
@return array('form' => CForm, 'options' => array) ... comment ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid, `@return array` is the best you can do, unless the array is homogeneous, in which case perhaps `@return array<MyClass>` would be more applicable.

Answer (score 1):

When you must return a weird array then document it just simple and easy to understand.

Here's how I would do it. Feel free to use `@return array` instead of `mixed[]`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Method to do something
 *
 * @param Some_User_Class $user
 * @param string $blockUserId
 * @throws Some_Model_Relations_ErrorException
 * @return mixed[] see example
 * @example The returned array consists of this
 *  and that and might have foo and bar.
 *  so this makes me feel like the code should be refactored.
 */
public function unblockUser(Some_User_Class $user, $unblockUserId) {
}
```

Comment: "@return array" is the "proper" option, given that "proper" was defined before returning complex arrays became more common.

"@return mixed[]" has evolved as a means to indicate "an array, whose datatypes of values are not the same".  Some IDEs have grown to recognize this usage.  When the values are all the same type, e.g. a class Foo, this can be "@return Foo[]".

I've always recognized this use case as a code smell, that nudges me into considering that a new class should be defined.  I ultimately end up returning that new class, "@return MyNewClass".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit overkill, but you *could* return an object with a specific interface, in stead of a regular array. Something like:

```
/**
 * @return ReturnObject
 */
public function yourMethod()
{
    return new ReturnObjectImpl( $theForm, $theOptions );
}

interface ReturnObject
{
    public function getCForm();
    public function getOptions();
}

class ReturnObjectImpl
    implements ReturnObject
{
    protected $_form;
    protected $_options;

    public function __construct( CForm $form, array $options )
    {
        $this->_form = $form;
        $this->_options = $options;
    }

    public function getCForm()
    {
        return $this->_form;
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```